# Download source via maven with maven-dependency-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I want to download a specific sources jar (guice-sources.jar) and I don't want it to download android sources. This would work on the terminal:

```
mvn dependency:sources -DincludeArtifactIds=android
```

and this works well too:

```
mvn dependency:sources -DincludeArtifactIds=guice
```

I config a plugin segment in the pom.xml as below,

```xml
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>default-cli</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>sources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <includeArtifactIds>guice</includeArtifactIds>
            <!--<excludeArtifactIds>android</excludeArtifactIds>-->
        </configuration>
    </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
```

and run this,it still downloads the android jar for me

```
mvn dependency:sources
```

I have tried to move the plugin part in a pluginManagement, didn't work either.
What's wrong with it?

Comment: Tried to use excludeArtifactIds=android on command line?

Comment: I'm confused - does your commented-out `excludeArtifactIds` statement have no effect?

Comment: i just need the guice source and don't need the android source. so i put includeArtifactIds property,it doesn't work ; i try with excludeArtifactIds to exclude the android source,it doesn't work too.

Comment: but this works fine:mvn dependency:sources -DincludeArtifactIds=guice

Comment: Ok , forget it. someone else tried with my setup and find it works well. I'll figure out it in the will.